Нужно суммировать цифры из ячеек, при этом игнорировать ячейки красного цвета, в Google Sheets
Есть таблица для подсчета данных, в которой обычные ячейки (белые) суммируются в конце строки, а красные должны игнорироваться
Посидев над задачей, я написал такой код в Apps Script:


function sumWithoutRed(range) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("range");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (backgrounds[i][j] != '##800080') {
        sum += parseFloat(values[i][j]) || 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
}



При этом нужно учитывать, что листов с данными много, в каждом из них должна применяться эта функция, местоположение ячеек меняется.


var range = sheet.getRange("range");



Я понимаю, что вместо range нужно написать диапазон ячеек, но это мне не подходит, так как ячейки, из листа в лист, меняют свое положение.
Главный вопрос: Как мне решить проблему с ячейками, чтобы код был гибким?
Пример работы функции в самой таблице:


Вам проще использовать не статичное указание листов, а динамичное через getSheets() (это массив листов). А для данных подойдёт функция getDataRange()

Чтобы правильно ответить на ваш запрос нужно несколько уточнений:

sumWithoutRed(range) - это должна быть пользовательская функция. Правильно я понимаю? Или это функция, которая будет использоваться внутри скрипта.  (по вашему примеру - это больше похоже на функцию для внутреннего использования в скрипте)
Суммируется диапазон в виде столбца с ячейками разного цвета, или диапазон в виде матрицы с ячейками разного цвета (по вашему примеру - это матрица).

Почему бы вместо конструкции For...For не использовать конструкции:

REDUCE...MAP или
REDUCE...REDUCE



По задумке, это пользовательская функция, которая будет использоваться в самой таблице.
не очень понял вопроса


@Blinovich если это пользовательская функция (которая пишется в ячейке), вам не нужно напрямую указывать range. Таблица возьмёт тот диапазон, который вы укажете. Но есть вопрос: что вы понимаете под "гибкостью" пользовательской функции?

Вашим комментарием вы ответили на вопрос по гибкости, спасибо
